# AutoCompleteTextField + GoogleMap in Codename One

Tags: codenameone

I tried to put an AutoCompleteTextField (used for address completion) and a Google Map peer component (using the cn1lib) in the same container, but it doesn’t work fine on real device (it's ok only in the Simulator).

Using a BoxLayout.y, the completion list appears only on iPhone but not on Android.

Using a BorderLayout.totalBelow, with Google Map in the center and the AutoCompleteTextField on the north, after selecting an address from the autocompletion list, the AutoCompleteTextField disappears (tested on iPhone).

Could you please give me any hint to make the two components working correctly? The cn1lib I’m using is updated. Thank you

```
Container innerContent = new Container(BorderLayout.totalBelow());

            // Start content
            AutoCompleteTextField autoCompleteTextField = (AutoCompleteTextField) InputUtilities.getAutoCompleteAddress(true);
            autoCompleteTextField.setUIID("BaseStructureForm-InnerBoxMap");

            // Google Map
            final MapContainer googleMap = new MapContainer() {
                @Override
                public Dimension calcPreferredSize() {
                    int width = contentBox.getWidth() - CN.convertToPixels(10, true);
                    int height = CN.convertToPixels(50, false);
                    return new Dimension(width, height);
                }
            };
            innerContent.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, autoCompleteTextField);
            innerContent.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, googleMap);
            // End content

            autoCompleteTextField.addListListener(e -> {
                String selectedItem = (String) ((com.codename1.ui.List) e.getSource()).getSelectedItem();
                String place_id = (String) autoCompleteTextField.getClientProperty("place_id");
                //googleMap.setCameraPosition(new Coord(43.0511, 10.8892274));
                GoogleMapUtilities.setMapPlace(place_id, (latitudine, longitude) -> {
                    googleMap.zoom(new Coord(latitudine, longitude), 3);
                });
            });
```

Comment: I edited the question adding the code.

Comment: There might be a regression here, can you add device screenshots?

Comment: The main cause of the issue was the line: `AutoCompleteTextField autoCompleteTextField = (AutoCompleteTextField) InputUtilities.getAutoCompleteAddress(true);`. I completely forgot that it returns a custom implementation of AutoCompleteTextField (because I wrote that method months ago for a specific use case, it overrides some methods of AutoCompleteTextField). I solved a lot of issues using the "original" version of this class. However, if I have other issues, I'll post a test case on github.